# which is better way to install jenkins docker or kubernetes

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, devops

I am new to devops. I want to install jenkins. So out of all options available to install jenkins provided in official documentation which one should I use. I am zeroed on docker or kubernetes. So parameters I am looking for decision are below.

1. portability - can be installed on any major os or cloud provider.
2. minimal changes to move to production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes is a container orchestrator that may use Docker as its container runtime. So, they are quite different things—essentially, different levels of abstraction.

You could theoretically run an application at both of these abstraction levels. Here's a comparison:

**Docker**

You can run an application as a Docker container on any machine that has Docker installed (i.e. any OS or cloud provider instance that supports Docker). However, you would need to implement any operations-related features that are relevant for production, such as health checks, replication, load balancing, etc. yourself.

**Kubernetes**

Running an application on Kubernetes requires a Kubernetes cluster. You can run a Kubernetes cluster either on-premises, in the cloud, or use a managed Kubernetes service (such as Amazon EKS, Google GKE, or Azure AKS). The big advantage of Kubernetes is that it provides all the production-relevant features mentioned above (health checks, replication, load balancing, etc.) as part of the platform. So, you don't need to implement them yourself but just use the primitives that Kubernetes provides to you.

---

Regarding your two requirements, Kubernetes provides both of them, while using Docker alone does not provide easy production-readiness (requirement 2). So, if you're opting for production stability, setting up a Kubernetes cluster is certainly worth the effort.

Comment: so in jenkins installation guide they are using minikube to install jenkins. So this minikube setup with some changes can be moved to production ? and how much chnages will be requred to do this ?

Comment: The Kubernetes installation instructions on https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/ can be applied to production with no changes. They use Minikube for people who don't already have a cluster, but you can do the same steps on a production cluster.